# Java method for easier validation for batch of Jcomponents containing null

Tags: java, swing, validation

This is a GUI Panel I'm working on. I was just thinking if there's any way to simplify the checking of empty fields, empty list and unselected checkboxes instead of writing multiple lines of

```
TextField1.getText().isempty()
checkBox1.isSelected()
list1.isEmpty()

TextField2.getText().isempty()
checkBox2.isSelected()
list2.isEmpty()
```

[image]

I want to reduce the number of lines or codes if possible. Maybe my question really is if it is possible to check whether a batch of components **within** a panel contains empty(null) or not. This will help me reduce the lines of codes if there's such a function or listener that does it. If there's no such method or listener, what are the other options?

There are other modules i'm working with that has more checkboxes and text fields that's why I asked.

I'd appreciate any suggestion or help.

Thanks.

Comment: You could break each group of fields down into individual components, which would the contain some kind of `isFormValid` method which would return `true` or `false`. You could introduce a series of methods which takes a `JComponent` reference, determines what type of component it is and does the physical validation, returning `true` or `false`, you could further enhance this by have a method which takes an array or list of components. This assumes the basic validation or each type of component is the same

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks. I haven't thought of that. I guess I'll need to play around more with these JComponents to take advantage of arrays etc.. I'll take your advice of putting them inside an array.